# How to operform Pandas groupby() multiplying values in grouped column by values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   A  B  count_of_elmt_A
0  x     10.0
1  x  k  3.0
2  y  l  NaN
3  z  j  4.0
```

I want to group the data by `A` and annotate the count of each element in `A` multiplied by `count_of_elmt_A`. Invalid rows in `count_of_elmt_A` should default to 1. So the result should be:

```
A
x    13 # 10 + 3, because row 0 has 10 for count_of_elmt_A, row 1 has 3.
y    1  # because row 2 has a NaN count_of_elmt_A, which defaults to 1.
z    4  # because row 3 has 4 in count_of_elmt_A.
```

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work as desired:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"A":["x","x","y","z"], "B": ["", "k", "l", "j"], "count_of_elmt_A": [10, 3, None, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df.groupby("A")["A"].count()
df2 = df2.mul(df["count_of_elmt_A"].fillna(1))
```

Comment: What does "the count of each element in A multiplied by the respective number in C" mean? there are 2 `x` in A, so how can you get 13 as a result?

Comment: and why `y` has `4` ?

Comment: I had mixed up `y` and `z`, `y` should be `1` and `z` should be `4`.
The result for `x` should be `13` because in the respective rows, `C` (now renamed to `count_of_elmt_A` for clarity) has the values 10 and 3, which should be summed.

Comment: `df['count_of_elmt_A'].fillna(1).groupby(df['A']).sum()`

Comment: This worked, thanks! I would accept this if it was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"A":["x","x","y","z"], "B": ["", "k", "l", "j"], "C": [10, 3, None, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda group: len(group['C'].dropna()) * group['C'].sum()).astype(int)
print(result)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.